# Homebrew Upgrade Outdated Formulae Output Clarification

Tags: homebrew, pydoc

I am using a mac (intel) running zsh terminal with the homebrew package manager. I recently upgraded some outdated formulae and received the following output.

1. pydocstyle archived

   > 

   ```
    pydocstyle has been disabled because it has an archived upstream repository!
   ```

   > 

--> I understand what this means, but it seems that pydocstyle is still an actively maintained package, what is the issue here and would the below solution still resolve this error to continue using the package?

This is from a stack overflow post about a similar issue when installing maven.

Deleting

```
disable! date: "2022-07-31", because: :unmaintained
```

& Adding

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install maven@3.5
```